# How do I save details (using NSUserDefaults) in a containers view controller from a save button in the view controller holding the container view?

Tags: xcode, swift2, nsuserdefaults, uicontainerview

Basically I have a view controller with a save button which holds a container view. Inside this container is a view table view controller of static cells which hold text fields. I would like to be able to save the information in these fields using NSUserDefaults with the save button in the top layer view controller.

I understand how to get this working in a single view controller but am having difficulties when incorporating it into a container view as described. Is this a case of pointing to the relevant information which requires saving?

Swift2, Xcode.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what have you tried so far ? Are you able to access the values in the tableView and having difficulty in saving them in userDefaults ?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Yes I'm having difficulty accessing the values themselves from the view controller which holds the container view.

Comment: in that case you need to show your code I guess, and your view hierarchy  as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase anyone has the same issue, I managed to achieve this by inserting the following just before viewDidLoad():

var containerViewController: "the containerViews VC?"
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "the embed segue from both VCs" {
            let connectContainerViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! "the containerViews VC"
            containerViewController = connectContainerViewController

I used this to provide a pointer (containerViewController) to the information in the containerViews VC in order to save the details using NSUserDefaults once the save button had been pressed in the VC holding the containerView.

Hope this helps anyone looking to do the same.